# R ggplot2 how to separate legend elements

Tags: r, ggplot2

I read this example data as CSV into an R dataframe

```
"TEST","PREVIOUS","LAST","Interaction"
0.592,0.689,0.708,"Insertion"
0.702,0.796,0.836,"Insertion"
0.687,0.738,0.738,"Circular permutation and repetition"
0.727,0.675,0.734,"Insertion"
0.944,0.919,0.925,"Insertion and conformational variability"
0.862,0.847,0.847,"Conformational variability"
0.808,0.763,0.827,"Insertion"
0.981,0.983,0.983,"Conformational variability"
0.703,0.786,0.788,"Circular permutation and conformational variability"
0.691,0.732,0.732,"Insertion and conformational variability"
0.659,0.641,0.655,"Insertion"
0.6,0.602,0.676,"Insertion and conformational variability"
0.355,0.704,0.707,"Circular permutation and insertion"
0.436,0.716,0.739,"Circular permutation and insertion"
0.386,0.677,0.699,"Circular permutation and insertion"
0.976,0.979,0.979,"Conformational variability"
0.73,0.757,0.757,"Circular permutation"
0.492,0.918,0.918,"Circular permutation"
0.688,0.672,0.685,"Circular permutation and insertion"
0.79,0.799,0.799,"Circular permutation"
0.756,0.817,0.834,"Circular permutation and insertion"
0.677,0.668,0.677,"Insertion"
0.892,0.884,0.89,"Conformational variability"
0.604,0.752,0.759,"Insertion and conformational variability"
0.589,0.721,0.73,"Insertion and repetition"
0.916,0.927,0.927,"Conformational variability and repetition"
0.665,0.667,0.667,"Insertion"
0.62,0.684,0.717,"Insertion"
0.683,0.714,0.714,"Circular permutation and conformational variability"
0.55,0.75,0.788,"Insertion"
0.584,0.67,0.704,"Insertion and repetition"
0.635,0.684,0.684,"Circular permutation"
0.45,0.605,0.623,"Insertion and conformational variability"
0.53,0.611,0.611,"Insertion"
0.792,0.778,0.811,"Insertion and repetition"
0.524,0.595,0.631,"Insertion"
0.591,0.719,0.771,"Insertion and conformational variability"
0.633,0.719,0.719,"Insertion"
0.785,0.803,0.816,"Insertion and repetition"
0.738,0.723,0.731,"Insertion and repetition"
```

Then I plot the following figure using ggplot and the following code:

```r
library(ggplot2)

fig = ggplot(dta, aes(x=LAST, y=TEST, fill=Interaction)) +
geom_point(
    dta[which(dta["LAST"] == dta["PREVIOUS"]),],
    mapping =aes(x=LAST,y=TEST),
    shape=21, size=3,stroke = 0.25, alpha=0.9)  +


geom_point(
    dta[which(dta["LAST"] != dta["PREVIOUS"]),],
    mapping =aes(x=LAST,y=TEST),
    shape=21, size=3, stroke = 0.25, alpha=0.9)  +


geom_point(
    dta[which(dta["LAST"] != dta["PREVIOUS"]),],
    mapping =aes(x=LAST,y=TEST),
    shape=3, size=1,stroke = 0.25)  +


xlim(0.4, 1.0) +
ylim(0.4, 1.0) +
theme(legend.position="top")+
     xlab("LAST") + ylab("TEST") +
     guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol=1, title=""))

p4b = p4b + coord_fixed()+guides(fill =guide_legend(ncol=2, title="Interactions", title.position="top",
                                                  title.theme = element_text(
                                                  size = 15,
                                                  face = "bold",
                                                  colour = "black",
                                                  margin=margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 5, unit = "pt")
                                                ) 
                                                 )
                                )
p4b
```

I obtain this figure. The problem is that what I want is a separate legend element that represents the "+" shape, without color. In the end, there should be 10 elements in the legend, the 9 actual coloured round shapes (but without the "+" inside) and 1 "+" alone.

I saw some people using `override.aes` in the `guid_legend` part, but I just wasn't able to make it work and I'm on this for too long now ...
[image]

Comment: You're more likely to get help faster if you maker your example **minimal**. Your 20 lines of `theme()` options aren't relevant to the legend. All the manually coded `hline` and `vline` and `abline`s aren't relevant, etc. If you simplify the code down to the bare essentials, your question becomes much more approachable.

Comment: Though I will comment to question why you're making grid lines manually rather than using theme options?

Comment: Sorry you are right, I just edited the code to simplify. I also saw that a part was missing. To answer your other question, it is only a matter of aesthetics preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working from the original post, where no points had associated + signs with them. Assuming these are drawn by a `geom_point` layer with shape = 3, taken from a subset of the data frame `dta` we can do:

```r
ggplot(dta, aes(TEST1, TEST, fill = Interaction)) +
  annotation_custom(grob = g3, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color="black", size = 1.0) +
  geom_abline(intercept = c(-0.05, 0.05),  slope = 1, 
              color = "black", linetype = "dotted", size = 0.25, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_abline(intercept = c(-0.1, 0.1), slope = 1, color = "black", 
              linetype = "dashed", size = 0.25, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4.5, stroke = 0.25, alpha = 0.9) +
  geom_point(aes(TEST1, TEST, shape = "Positive"), inherit.aes = FALSE,
             size = 1.5, data = dta[sample(nrow(dta), 12),]) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 3, name = "Special") +
  xlim(0.4, 1.0) +
  ylim(0.4, 1.0) +
  theme(legend.position="top",
        legend.key.height= unit(.4, 'cm'),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = "gray"),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.box.background = element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black",size = 13, face = "bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size=15, face = "bold")
       ) +
     xlab("TEST1") + 
  ylab("TEST") +
  coord_fixed() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2, 
                             title = "Interactions", 
                             title.position = "top",
                             title.theme = 
                               element_text(
                                  size = 15,
                                  face = "bold",
                                  colour = "black",
                                  margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 5, 
                                                  unit = "pt")
                                                ) 
                              ),
         shape = guide_legend(title = "Special", 
                             title.position = "top",
                             title.theme = element_text(
                                  size = 15,
                                  face = "bold",
                                  colour = "black",
                                  margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 5, 
                                                  unit = "pt")
                                                ) 
                              ))
```

[image]

Note I also had to try to reconstruct the `g3` object from an educated guess.